My USB ports stopped working in Linux. Both Mint and Arch. What is causing this and how do I fix it?
It was about half a year ago when after an update My USB ports while using Arch stopped working. They work in the UEFI settings so I know it's not a problem with the hardware. I tried turning off auto-suspend. This also did not work. Finally I decided to reinstall Arch. The USB worked during installation but broke after rebooting. I was hoping the issue would resolve itself with another update, but it did not. I just now installed Mint and the USB ports still don't work.
My mouse light flashes but doesn't stay on. lsusb shows the root hubs are on:
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 27c6:538d Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. FingerPrint
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0cf3:e009 Qualcomm Atheros Communications 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

lsblk only shows my internal storage when I plug in a USB flash drive.
My hdmi, SD card, and audio ports all still work.
dmesg | grep usb shows the same thing whether something is plugged in or not:
[    0.256192] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.256192] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.256192] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.873238] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 5.15
[    0.873240] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.873241] usb usb1: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    0.873243] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 5.15.0-113-generic xhci-hcd
[    0.873244] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    0.875780] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 5.15
[    0.875783] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.875784] usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    0.875785] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 5.15.0-113-generic xhci-hcd
[    0.875786] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    0.876379] usb: port power management may be unreliable
[    1.210636] usb 1-5: new full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    1.364726] usb 1-5: New USB device found, idVendor=27c6, idProduct=538d, bcdDevice= 1.00
[    1.364732] usb 1-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    1.364735] usb 1-5: Product: FingerPrint
[    1.364737] usb 1-5: Manufacturer: Goodix
[    1.490609] usb 1-10: new full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    1.644061] usb 1-10: New USB device found, idVendor=0cf3, idProduct=e009, bcdDevice= 0.01
[    1.644069] usb 1-10: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    3.677825] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb

The bottom of my laptop has slightly fallen out in the back (maybe a millimeter).
lsmod | grep usb only shows Bluetooth modules loaded:
btusb                  61440  0
btrtl                  24576  1 btusb
btbcm                  24576  1 btusb
btintel                40960  1 btusb
bluetooth             704512  43 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="iommu=soft" also does not work.
What is causing this and how do I fix it?

what is your question?  ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post
